# How to authenticate Kubernetes application with Vault using AppRole method

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, vault

My application runs on Kubernetes and it requires some sensitive data in order to run the application. For example, DB username and password. Currently I'm passing those sensitive vaules as environment variables in the Kubernetes definition file.

Since this way is not safe, I deployed vault and now I need to authenticate my application with vault. I also created secrets in vault and I'm using 'AppRole' method to authenticate. I obtain the RoleID and SecretID.

How do I specify and authenticate with vault from my application? Is it enough to pass RoleID and SecretID as environmental variables in my Kubernetes deployment file?

Comment: Why not use the Kubernetes authentication engine instead?

Comment: What is "(secure) enough" depends on a lot of things, namely your security requirements. AppRole authentication is easier to configure than K8S, espescially if you intend to use groups and entity aliases to manage permissions. But where will you store the AppRole credentials to pass to your deployment file? In Vault - good idea - but where will you store the credentials used to authenticate to Vault in the first place? Secure secret introduction is a hard problem, Kubernetes authentication is a solution to it. But nothing is free.

Comment: @ixe013 So passing AppRole credentials in the code is not enough? Other than defining the AppRole credentials in the code, do we need to specify them in any other place also? Like in deployment manifest?

Comment: Yes, it is enough for AppRole authentication to work. Might not be enough to satisfy a security auditor looking at your deployment code. At the very least, do not store the credentials *in* the code, in your source code repository.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible to use `AppRole` auth method for your use-case, as the approle auth method allows machines or apps to authenticate with Vault-defined roles.

Enable `AppRole` auth method, create necessary `policies` for your application & generate `role_id`, `secret_id`. You can create a K8s secret containing these values.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: auth-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  VAULT_APPROLE_ROLE_ID: <role_id>
  VAULT_APPROLE_SECRET_ID: <secret_id>
```

Now, refer to it in your application:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: <image_name>
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
      envFrom:
      - secretRef:
          name: auth-secret
```